# select interbase and insert to mysql show 1 record only

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, interbase

I try to get data from another machine which use interbase. I'm using PDO to insert the interbase value to Mysql. But just one record which inserted to mysql. Why?

```
$stmt = "SELECT FIRST 10 TRIM(LINE_NAME) as LINE_NAME, TRIM(MODEL_NAME) as MODEL_NAME, TRIM(PROD_NO) as PROD_NO,
                        TRIM(LOT_SIZE_IN) as LOT_SIZE_IN,TRIM(START_SERIAL) as START_SERIAL, 
                        TRIM(SERIAL_NO_LOW) as SERIAL_NO_LOW, TRIM(SERIAL_NO_UP) as SERIAL_NO_UP, TRIM(PROD_DATE) as PROD_DATE 
                FROM DOC_TO";
    $sth = ibase_query($dbh, $stmt);

// CREATE AN ARRAY OF OBJECTS
if($sth === FALSE) {
    die(ibase_errmsg()); // TODO: better error handling
}

        while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($sth)) {
                $newvalues[] = $row;
                }

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=qdbase', 'root', 'JeinQA123');

$sql="TRUNCATE TABLE `schedule`";
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
if($stmt){echo "connected";}
else{echo "failed";}


// PREPARE A QUERY
$qry2 = "INSERT INTO schedule (line,model,lotno,qty,serial,seriallow,serialup,date ) 
                VALUES (:LINE_NAME, :MODEL_NAME, :PROD_NO,:LOT_SIZE_IN,:START_SERIAL,:SERIAL_NO_LOW,:SERIAL_NO_UP,:PROD_DATE)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($qry2);

// USE THE ARRAY OF OBJECTS
foreach ($newvalues as $obj)
{
    // BIND THE OBJECT PROPERTIES INTO THE QUERY
    $stmt->bindParam('LINE_NAME',   $obj->LINE_NAME);
    $stmt->bindParam('MODEL_NAME', $obj->MODEL_NAME);
    $stmt->bindParam('PROD_NO', $obj->PROD_NO);
    $stmt->bindParam('LOT_SIZE_IN', $obj->LOT_SIZE_IN);
    $stmt->bindParam('START_SERIAL', $obj->START_SERIAL);
    $stmt->bindParam('SERIAL_NO_LOW', $obj->SERIAL_NO_LOW);
    $stmt->bindParam('SERIAL_NO_UP', $obj->SERIAL_NO_UP);
    $stmt->bindParam('PROD_DATE', $obj->PROD_DATE); 

/*I try to add this inside foreach*/
    try
    {
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    // IF THERE IS AN EXCEPTION THROWN BY PDO
    catch (PDOException $exc)
    {
        // IF THE EXCEPTION NUMBER IS NOT "DUPLICATE UNIQUE"
        if ($exc->errorInfo[1] != 1062)
        {
            $msg = "FAIL: $qry " . PHP_EOL . $exc->getmessage();
            trigger_error($msg, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So wait, now you want to ignore unique constraint violations? Why didn't you mention that initially?

Comment: Looks like you haven't set PDO to actually throw exceptions so there won't be any to catch in case of an error. See my updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
// make sure PDO is set to throw exceptions
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($qry2);

foreach ($newvalues as $obj) {
    try {
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':LINE_NAME'     => $obj->LINE_NAME,
            ':MODEL_NAME'    => $obj->MODEL_NAME,
            ':PROD_NO'       => $obj->PROD_NO,
            ':LOT_SIZE_IN'   => $obj->LOT_SIZE_IN,
            ':START_SERIAL'  => $obj->START_SERIAL,
            ':SERIAL_NO_LOW' => $obj->SERIAL_NO_LOW,
            ':SERIAL_NO_UP'  => $obj->SERIAL_NO_UP,
            ':PROD_DATE'     => $obj->PROD_DATE
        ));
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
        if ($errorInfo[1] != 1062) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure that `1062` is the error code to be checking for. In the past, I've used `1586` to detect unique constraint violations. Trial and error will discover the right value to check.

You were also using `$stmt->errorInfo` as a property instead of the method `$stmt->errorInfo()`.

Comment: show error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'`

Comment: @nunu You're obviously on a pretty old version of PHP. The shorthand array syntax came in 5.4. I've updated my answer to support the legacy syntax

Comment: I try to execute, look at my updated question. still get same error after change to your updated answer.

Comment: @nunu Did you set PDO to throw exceptions (see first line of code above)? Try running it without the `try` statement and `catch` block. Also make sure you've set `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On` in your `php.ini` file

Comment: @nunu I assume from the *accept* that you got it working. Congrats :)

Comment: I have deleted my last comment cause i have found another error come to mysql.I forgot to change auto increment so after error is gone the data still not insert.that's my fault so, I cancel my last comment,lol.